# Finding a recurrence for number of paths in a certain tree

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

I have a graph which looks like this:

[image: A graph]

The question is to find a recurrence for $a_n$ - the number of paths of length $n$ that start in vertex $A$. How do you tackle these kind of problems? There is obviously something I need to notice, but what is it?

Comment: to make sure, do you mean simple paths? (paths without repeated vertices)

Comment: no, just any paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph is bipartite, and the set that contains $A$ contains only three vertices, so we can write a recurrence for them. Denoting the number of paths of length $n$ that start at the mirror image of $A$ by $b_n$ and those that start at the lower centre vertex by $c_n$, we have

$$
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}_{n+2}=\pmatrix{3&1&1\\1&3&1\\1&1&1}\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}_n\;.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Where does that recurrence stem from? Is is that if we choose to go down or up from $a$ we have to go back no matter what and hence $a_{n+2}$? $3a_n$ because all three vertices in the middle act the same? But why $b_n$? You say it's the mirror image... So I got it wrong. It should be that if we start from $A$ or it's mirror image then we can go up down and to the left/right and then go back or go twice left/right to get to $b_n/a_n$ or go left/right down to get to $c_n$. Did I get it right? Oh boy, I got complicated.

Comment: I think I see it anyway!

Comment: @Jules: I'm afraid I wasn't able to parse all of that :-) To explain the first row of the matrix: There are $3$ ways to get from $A$ to $A$ in two steps (one for each of the neighbours), so any path of length $n$ starting at $A$ can be extended to a path of length $n+2$ starting at $A$ by prepending two steps in $3$ ways. There is $1$ way to get from the mirror image to $A$ in two steps, and $1$ way to get from the lower centre to $A$ in two steps. For the bottom row: From each of the three vertices, there is only $1$ way to get to the lower centre in two steps.